# Nominatim boundingbox limit?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm trying to search for example for fuel (Tankstelle) in an area.

this is a boundingbox of 50km and it gives only little results:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Tankstelle&format=xml&limit=50&viewbox=7.98435,49.40889,8.95440,48.77371&bounded=1
```

It contains a "more_url" link to get more data. Although I'm using the limit-parameter I only get few results. Is it somehow possible at least to get as much results as specified with limit instead of this more_url?

Tom

Comment: It might be worth trying to ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org or at the official bug tracker at [Nominatim's github project](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (trying to be more explicit)

If you want to search OSM "features" with Nominatim, you should use the dedicated - even if undocumented! - Nominatim syntax, using [Special Phrases](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases) inside brackets:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=[Tankstelle]&format=xml&limit=50&viewbox=7.98435,49.40889,8.95440,48.77371&bounded=1
```

Restrictions to use this syntax:

- You MUST set a viewbox, and bounded=1.
- The maximum value for limit is 50.

You can see that your query retrieves 4 results (with "Tankstelle" in the address), when my query retrieves the max = 50 (50 fuel stations, even without "Tankstelle" in the address).

I have no idea why Nominatim proposes more_url to your search example.

Now, if you search for regular addresses ("q=50 Mozart street, Denver"), then Nominatim normally sticks to the  limit you set (50). If Nominatim finds more than 50 answers, then more_url allows to get the next "page" of 50 results (and so on).

Comment: My question was actually not, how to find Tankstelle, its just a sample. I want to know, how to query something/anything in a bounding box with a limit and get exactly one response with all results and no more_url.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving all fuel stations in a given area it is better to use a different API, for example [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). Nominatim is mainly a (reverse) geocoder and not designed for such queries.

See [this example query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4SR) showing all fuel stations in your bounding box, visualized using [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo):

```xml
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <union>
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="fuel"/>
      <bbox-query e="8.95440" n="49.40889" s="48.77371" w="7.98435"/>
    </query>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="fuel"/>
      <bbox-query e="8.95440" n="49.40889" s="48.77371" w="7.98435"/>
    </query>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="amenity" v="fuel"/>
      <bbox-query e="8.95440" n="49.40889" s="48.77371" w="7.98435"/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

Comment: ok thanks, but more precise my question was actually how to avoid this more_url in Nominatin and get all hits up to limit in one answer.

Comment: btw. Nominatim is doing this very good. From the user-side its much easier to query for Tankstelle then to deal with tags and values in Overpass.

Comment: That's right, but overpass turbo's wizard also accepts "Tankstelle" and similar keywords.